# Jmeter - bearer token

Tags: jmeter

I recorded a script using jmeter and i'm getting 3 different errors related to authentication.  Any ideas on how to fix it?  Thank you.

1. ErrorUnable to authenticate bearer token

[image: Unable to authenticate bearer token error]

2. {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"UNKNOWN_CLIENT: Client was not identified by any client authenticator"}

[image: Unknown client error]

3. {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token invalid: Token is not active"}

[image: Token invalid error]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the application you are testing with JMeter uses token authentication. Either your test cases (scripts) will need to include a step to obtain a valid token (this is best practice, and what I would recommend), or you will need to update the application to use a special testing token that never expires (this is kind of hacky, prone to breakage, and may not even be possible if you can't make changes to the application code).

Comment: Hi C, yes, the app uses token authentication.  Do you know exactly how to extra the token and pass it in jmeter ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [OAuth 2.0 SAML Bearer Assertion Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_SAML_bearer_flow.htm&type=5) I don't think you will be able to "extract" the token, most probably you will need to **generate** it. The algorithm may vary depending on your application configuration so you'd better reach out to your application developers in order to clarify the login flow.

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) to learn more about the concept of bypassing [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) login challenges in JMeter tests.